# access control, role and permission in grails

Tags: grails, permissions, roles, access-control, shiro

I am working on a grails application for the first time and I now want to protect some pages to be viewed only by admins, and give some permissions to other users.

I am using Apache Shiro plugin for grails.

My sample code in the bootstrap looks like this

```
class BootStrap {

def init = { servletContext ->
    def adminRole

    if(ShiroRole.findByName("Admin".isEmpty())){
        adminRole = new ShiroRole(name: "Administrator")
        adminRole.addToPermissions("*:*")
        adminRole.addToPermissions("admin")

        adminRole.save()
```

// 'user' now has all administrator rights
        }

```
    if (ShiroUser.findAllByUsername("user").isEmpty()) {
        def user = new ShiroUser(username: "user", passwordHash: new Sha256Hash("pass").toHex())
        user.addToPermissions("*:*")
        user.addToRoles(adminRole)

        user.save()

    }

    if (ShiroUser.findAllByUsername("Guest").isEmpty()) {
        def user = new ShiroUser(username: "Guest", passwordHash: new Sha256Hash("pass").toHex())
        user.addToPermissions("inventory:*")
        user.save()
    }


}
def destroy = {
}
```

}

My ShiroSecurityFilters  looks like

```
class ShiroSecurityFilters {
def filters = {
    all(uri: "/**") {
        before = {
            // Ignore direct views (e.g. the default main index page).
            if (!controllerName) return true

            // Access control by convention.
            accessControl()

        }
    }
}
```

}

I wanted to give to "Guest" access to **inventory** scaffold only. However in my application once the user "Guest" logged in its able to access other controllers butI don't want that to happen. I appreciate your help.

If there is an better of using Shiro role, access control and/or permissions, please let me know about it.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK. let's see...

there is a typo right at the start:

```
"Admin".isEmpty()
```

will always be false... and I guess you have no role "false" defined...

And you are looking for "Admin" but create "Administrator"...

Do a

```
adminRole.save(flush:true, failOnError:true)
```

instead of `adminRole.save()`. This will make sure that the object is really saved.

The role `Administrator` already has all permissions (`"*:*"`) and `"admin"` is not a typical shiro permission, so you can drop this line... (`adminRole.addToPermissions("admin")`)

If you do a

```
user.addToRoles(adminRole)
```

you don't need to add the `"*:*"`permission. The role is already enough.

I've now created a test project, installed shiro, did a `create-auth-controller`, a `create-wildcard-realm` and a `create-filters ShiroSecurity`.

Activate logging for BootStrap and Shiro-Realm by adding following two lines to the log4j config in Config.groovy:

```
debug   'grails.app.conf.BootStrap'
debug   'grails.app.realm'
```

Here is my BootStrap.groovy: (the interesting part)

```
def init = { servletContext ->
    def adminRole

    if(ShiroRole.findByName("Administrator")==null){
        adminRole = new ShiroRole(name: "Administrator")
        adminRole.addToPermissions("*:*")
        adminRole.save(flush:true, failOnError:true)
        log.debug adminRole.dump()
    }
    println ShiroUser.findAllByUsername("user").dump()
    log.debug "="*80
    if (ShiroUser.findAllByUsername("user").isEmpty()) {
        def user = new ShiroUser(username: "user", passwordHash: new Sha256Hash("pass").toHex())
        user.addToRoles(adminRole)
        user.save(flush:true, failOnError:true)
        log.debug user.dump()
    }

    if (ShiroUser.findAllByUsername("Guest").isEmpty()) {
        def user = new ShiroUser(username: "Guest", passwordHash: new Sha256Hash("pass").toHex())
        user.addToPermissions("inventory:*")
        user.save(flush:true, failOnError:true)
        log.debug user.dump()
    }

}
```

and my ShiroSecurityFilters.groovy:

```
def filters = {
    all(controller:'*', action:'*') {
        before = {
        // Ignore direct views (e.g. the default main index page).
        if (!controllerName) return true

        // Access control by convention.
        accessControl()

        }
    }
}
```

and it works...

As you can see, my SecurityFilters are based on controller and action... just my preference...

But I guess your problem was only based on the wrong bootstrap. Logging is very useful when you work with shiro...